# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, shutdown

Here is the screenshot of my XAMPP Control panel:

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is my Error Log :

```
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1791378
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-27  7:54:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-27  7:54:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1791387; transaction id 163
2019-11-27  7:54:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-27  7:54:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191127  7:54:15
2019-11-27  7:54:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-27  7:54:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2039505
2019-11-28  5:07:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 2039514; transaction id 684
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28  5:07:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28  5:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2040167
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 2040176; transaction id 700
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28  5:10:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28  5:14:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2040845
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 2040854; transaction id 711
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28  5:14:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28  5:19:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=5222673
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 5222682; transaction id 1347
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28  5:19:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=8402858
2019-11-28  5:28:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*5242880 to 2*524288000 bytes; LSN=8402876
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 524288000 bytes
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 524288000 bytes
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=8402876
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 8402876; transaction id 1981
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28  5:28:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28 22:10:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=27153381
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 27153390; transaction id 4845
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28 22:10:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=27184739
2019-11-28 23:46:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 27184748; transaction id 4940
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-28 23:46:46 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-29  4:50:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=27189447
2019-11-29  4:50:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-29  4:50:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-29  4:50:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
```

Comment: no errors in log. Look for a blocked port.

Comment: You need the log from _before_ the crash, not after.

Answer (score 14):

I came across similar problem and tried this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561) by [Fabrizio Valencia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5373542/fabrizio-valencia). It worked.

> **Stop there! Please do not delete anything! First try to do what I did.**
>
> OK, none of the listed answers here solved my problem, even, some of
> the answers were making me lost all my db data. So I did exactly what
> the error message in XAMPP message panel told me to do. So I did this:
>
> 1. Rename the folder `mysql/data` to `mysql/data_old` (you can use any name)
> 2. Create a new folder `mysql/data`
> 3. Copy the content that resides in `mysql/backup` to the new `mysql/data` folder
> 4. Copy all your database folders that are in `mysql/data_old` to `mysql/data`
> 5. Finally copy the `ibdata1` file from `mysql/data_old` and replace it inside `mysql/data` folder
> 6. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel
>
> And, voilà. No databases lost, no ports changed, no run as
> administrator, no force recovery, no kill mysqld process, no restoring
> from previous versions, no more errors.

Comment: Good thing I came across your answer. Thanks aton.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks very much for posting this solution.

Comment: By doing this dbs and tables are restored successfully but functions and procedures couldnot be restored, is there anyway to restore functions and procedures too?

Answer (score -1):

**IT WORKS FOR ME (Partially) : Please read all**

I copied all data (folders and files) from "**xampp\mysql\backup**" and pasted and replaced it inside "**xampp\mysql\data**". That's all...

**Note:** *Make sure you have backup of these two folders ("backup" & "data") including files and folders in another place. So that you can rollback anytime.*

**Warning:** Another problem arose for me. I was unable to access few Tables from different Databases. DB Tables Rows,Type, Size, Overhead columns are empty and Collation column is showing "*in use*".

[image: Database table's list]

But, it was okay for me. Because most of them are running. But, Still I am looking for the answer. For that reason, I am sharing my MySQL logs before and after fixing the problem. So that it might help others to find the actual reason.

**MySQL Logs: Before fixing the issue (2020-07-22 10:18:46)**

```
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1352041099
InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
InnoDB: Setting file 'DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
InnoDB: File 'DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 1352041108; transaction id 134006
Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200722 10:18:53
Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

**MySQL Logs: After fixing the issue (2020-07-22 15:34:45)**

```
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300638
InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
InnoDB: Setting file 'DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
InnoDB: File 'DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 300647; transaction id 195  
InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200722 15:34:46
```

**MySQL Logs: First log about 8 months before. (2019-12-05 22:27:34)**

```
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
InnoDB: Setting file 'DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
InnoDB: File 'DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from DRIVE:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191205 22:27:34
```

**Note:** *Here DRIVE means computer partition, i.e. C drive or D drive.*